# iOS Prefix.pch best practices

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pch

I have seen many developers that add various convenience macros to the Prefix.pch of their iOS projects.

What do (or don't) you recommend adding to the iOS Prefix.pch file? What does your Prefix.pch look like?

Comment: A detailed blog post on the subject: http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/02/my-current-prefix-pch-file/

Comment: Simply put your macros into a header file, for example `Macros.h`, and then import this file into your `prefix.pch`.

Comment: I'm also facing same issue... how to resolve in Xcode 6.1

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Ewww… don't put macros in a .pch file! A .pch file is, by definition, a project specific precompiled header. It really shouldn't be used beyond the context of the project and it really shouldn't contain anything but `#include`s and `#import`s.

If you have some macros and such that you want to share between headers, then stick 'em in a header file of their own — `Common.h` or whatever — and `#include` *that* at the beginning of the .pch.

Comment: What would you include in that Common.h?

Comment: Nothing;  I'd only put the various #defines, etc... in it.

Answer (score 38):

For modern iOS and OS X, people should be using **Modules**. This is enabled by default for new projects, and importing/inclusion is accomplished using `@import`.

Modules allow the compiler to create an intermediate representation of the contents of a module (e.g. a framework's headers). Much like a PCH, this intermediate representation may be shared across multiple translations. But modules take this one step further because a module is not necessarily target specific, and their declarations need not be localized (to a `*.pch`). This representation can save you a ton redundant compiler work.

Using modules, you do not need a PCH, and you probably should just do away with them entirely -- in favor of using `@import` local to the dependency. In that case, a PCH is only saving you from *typing* inclusions local to dependencies (which IMO you should be doing anyway).

Now, if we look back to the original question: You should avoid filling your PCH with all sorts of random things; Macros, constants, `#defines`, and all sorts of little libraries. Generally, you should **omit what really is unnecessary to the majority of your source files**. Putting all sorts of stuff in your PCH is just adding a bunch of weight and dependency. I see people put everything they link and more to in the PCH. In reality, auxiliary frameworks typically only need to be visible to a few translations in most cases. E.g. "Here is our StoreKit stuff - let's import StoreKit only where it **must** be visible. Specifically, these 3 translations". This keeps your build times down, and helps you keep track of your dependencies, so that you may reuse code more easily. So in an ObjC project, you would usually stop at Foundation. If there is a lot of UI, then you might consider adding UIKit or AppKit to your PCH. This is all assuming you want to optimize build times. One of the problems with large PCHs that include (nearly) everything is that removing unnecessary dependencies is very time consuming. Once your project's dependencies grow and your build times go up, you need to fight back by eliminating unnecessary dependencies in order to reduce your build times. Also, anything that changes often should generally be kept out of your PCH. A change requires a full rebuild. There are some options to share PCHs. If you use PCHs, do aim to support sharing.

As far as what I put in my PCH: I stopped using them for the vast majority of targets years ago. There just usually is not enough in common to qualify. Bear in mind, I write C++, ObjC, ObjC++ and C - the compiler emits one for each lang in your target. So enabling them often resulted in slower compile times and higher I/O. Ultimately, increasing dependency is not a good way to fight dependency in complex projects. Working with multiple languages/dialects, there are is much variation in the dependencies required for a given target. No, I would not advise that as optimal for every project, but that does give some perspective to dependency management in larger projects.

---

References

- http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html
- http://clang.llvm.org/docs/PCHInternals.html

---

Notes

- This question was originally asked a few years before Modules' introduction.
- Presently (Xcode 5.0), modules work for C and ObjC, but not C++.

Comment: What does it mean by complete rebuild for a module enabled project. You know this new -Swift.h bridging header is definitely not a right candidate for a .pch. But I have seen people do that. So as you can see if someone do that. We have a always changing header in .pch. So it rebuild everything in the .pch file every time the -Swift.h regenerated. Do you agree with this? You have more inputs?

Comment: @MadNik Suppose your app's PCH includes a master header of a library/framework which you are actively developing. For example: `#import "MyLib/MyLib.h"`. Anytime a file included by `MyLib.h` changes, every source file in the app must be recompiled. If you use MyLib in just one source file, then only that file must be recompiled when MyLib changes. Believe it or not, I'm not using any PCH files these days.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with bbum. My take on the PCH file is that it should contain pretty much only `#include` or `#import` statements. So if you have a bunch of helpful, high-level macros, define them in something like `Common.h` and `#import` that file, as bbum suggested.

I usually go a step further and use the PCH file to `#import` a file called `XXCategories.h` (where `XX` is the class naming prefix convention you use) that contains `#import`s for all my UIKit and Foundation class categories: `NSString+XXAdditions.h`, `UIColor+XXAdditons.h`, etc.

Comment: I'm just curious. In the .PCH file ,what's the difference between importing a Common.h which has various `#import` and just importing those `#import` directly? Wouldn't those be the same?, or does it affect any performance?

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no *real* difference. It's more of a best practice, I guess. Rather than shoving a bunch of macros and other things into your PCH file, it should only be for `#import` and `#include`.

Comment: The difference is re-usability. The PCH is project specific. The Common.h would be common to many projects. It's akin to asking why you don't just put all your util classes into your project instead of creating a sub project that you can reuse. Albeit a contrived example, because it's only a simple copy paste... but copy paste is naughty.

Answer (score 6):

create an header file "macros.h"

import this header into Prefix.pch

In this macros.h put all the frameworks and other important things.

If you are worried about performance, don't worry, look what apple says:

Headers and Performance

> If you are worried that including a master header file may cause your
>   program to bloat, don’t worry. Because OS X interfaces are implemented
>   using frameworks, the code for those interfaces resides in a dynamic
>   shared library and not in your executable. In addition, only the code
>   used by your program is ever loaded into memory at runtime, so your
>   in-memory footprint similarly stays small.
>         As for including a large number of header files during compilation, once again, don’t worry. Xcode provides a precompiled
>   header facility to speed up compile times. By compiling all the
>   framework headers at once, there is no need to recompile the headers
>   unless you add a new framework. In the meantime, you can use any
>   interface from the included frameworks with little or no performance
>   penalty.

also in my macros.h I put a lot of constants like:

```
// delegate
#define UIAppDelegate (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
#define APPDELEGATE   ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])

// system
#define IS_IPHONE_4INCH (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==568)
#define IS_IPAD                     (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

// screen size
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_4 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6PLUS (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale] == 3.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736.0)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0)
#define IS_RETINA_DISPLAY ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))
#define IS_PORTRAIT                 UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])
#define IS_LANDSCAPE                UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])

//system version
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)

// math
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
#define RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))

// cores
#define RGB(r,g,b)    [UIColor colorWithRed:(r)/255.0 green:(g)/255.0 blue:(b)/255.0 alpha:1]
#define RGBA(r,g,b,a) [UIColor colorWithRed:(r)/255.0 green:(g)/255.0 blue:(b)/255.0 alpha:a]
#define MAKECOLOR(R, G, B, A) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)R/255.0f) green:((float)G/255.0f) blue:((float)B/255.0f) alpha:A]
#define MAKECOLORFROMHEX(hexValue) [UIColor colorWithRed: ((float)((hexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((hexValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(hexValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]



//customizations
#define SHOW_STATUS_BAR               [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
#define HIDE_STATUS_BAR               [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

#define SHOW_NAVIGATION_BAR           [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:FALSE];
#define HIDE_NAVIGATION_BAR           [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE];

#define VC_OBJ(x) [[x alloc] init]
#define VC_OBJ_WITH_NIB(x) [[x alloc] initWithNibName : (NSString *)CFSTR(#x) bundle : nil]

#define RESIGN_KEYBOARD [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];

#define CLEAR_NOTIFICATION_BADGE                       [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
#define REGISTER_APPLICATION_FOR_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)]

#define HIDE_NETWORK_ACTIVITY_INDICATOR                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
#define SHOW_NETWORK_ACTIVITY_INDICATOR                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
```

Comment: Another useful here: `#define async(...) dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), __VA_ARGS__ )` ... to run blocks on the main thread: `async(^{ self.someLabel.text = @":D"; });`