# Should I put all header file into Prefix.pch?

Tags: objective-c

Is it recommended to refer to all my header file in Prefix.pch, and then I do not have to type #import headers during development?

Comment: u can put those header, u can used it throughout the project. not all the headers ... see this link as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845211/ios-prefix-pch-best-practices

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I add all the headers to Prefix.pch, and I have to claim life is much easier since that time. I just do not have to import always headers, believe me, life is much easier. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend this.

The main reason is, header files can change in the course of your development. If you change one header, it will cause the pch to dirty, have to be rebuilt, and now your entire project will rebuild. That's quite time-consuming, and works counter to the whole reason for pch files.

Same thing if you create a new header file, add it to the pch, and now that triggers and entire rebuild.

But there's no single answer here. You may have a 3rd party library that will never (or rarely) change, is quite header-intensive, and so precompiling it may be a way to reduce build times. Experiment and see.

Answer (score 2):

Pre-compiled header files were brought to serve one purpose: **to make compiling faster**. It is compiled and stored in cache, and automatically included in every source file during the compilation time. Its like each source file does,

```
#import "Prefix.h"
```

This can be handy for project-wide #defines. (FYI, #defines are a code smell)

Xcode quotes:

> Precompiling the prefix header will be most effective if the contents
>   of the prefix header or any file it includes change rarely. If the
>   contents of the prefix header or any file it includes change
>   frequently, there may be a negative impact to overall build time.

More clear explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462288/why-do-xcode-templates-have-imports-that-duplicate-prefix-pch/6462924#6462924)

Please keep this in mind when you #import source file header in .pch. As a tip, you can use Prefix.h for #import of constants and utility source files.

Answer (score 0):

From a standards perspective, your includes should be as minimal as possible. Indeed, you shouldn't include anything you don't require for compilation into any file. So, in each of your .h files you should primarily include the superclass and use `@class` for all other references, then include only in your .m files. This gives the clearest information about the requirements of each class / file and minimises circularity issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should add header file to Prefix.pch just if you need that file/class in most of your other classes. If you need the header file just in one or two other classes it's not point to add it to .pch because it will takes more time for compiler to compile the files and it will happen every time you want to run your project.